# How do I parse in the arguments to my Python training file when running the Sagemaker pipeline's TrainingStep?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to parse in arguments from my previous ProcessingStep into a custom python script in SageMaker pipelines, as shown below.

```
xgb_estimator = XGBoost(
        entry_point=os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "xgboost_train.py"),
        output_path=model_path,
        code_location=model_path,
        hyperparameters=hyperparams,
        role=role,
        # Fetch instance type and count from pipeline parameters
        instance_count=1,
        instance_type=training_instance_type,
        framework_version="1.3-1",
    )

    # Access the location where the preceding processing step saved train and validation datasets
    # Pipeline step properties can give access to outputs which can be used in succeeding steps
    s3_input_train = TrainingInput(
        s3_data=step_process.properties.ProcessingOutputConfig.Outputs[
            "train"
        ].S3Output.S3Uri,
        content_type="text/csv",
        # s3_data_type="S3Prefix",
    )
    s3_input_validation = TrainingInput(
        s3_data=step_process.properties.ProcessingOutputConfig.Outputs[
            "validation"
        ].S3Output.S3Uri,
        content_type="text/csv",
        # s3_data_type="S3Prefix",
    )

    # Set pipeline training step
    step_train = TrainingStep(
        name="TrainHDBResaleXGBModel",
        estimator=xgb_estimator,
        inputs={
            "train": s3_input_train,  # Train channel
            "validation": s3_input_validation,  # Validation channel
        },
    )
```

In my xgboost_train.py, I tried to access the inputs train and validation using:

```
# Set location of input training data
parser.add_argument("--train", type=str)
# Set location of input validation data
parser.add_argument("--validation", type=str)

data_train = pd.read_csv(f"{args.train}/train.csv")
data_validation = pd.read_csv(f"{args.validation}/validation.csv")
```

But `args.train` and `args.validation` keeps defaulting to `None`. How do I actually get the train and validation channel inputs I passed into `TrainingStep` inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking in the documentation under "[Prepare a Training script](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html#prepare-a-training-script)":

> you can access useful properties about the training environment through various environment variables

Therefore, when you input a data channel as in your case, you will refer to specially created environment variables.

Your code becomes:

```py
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

# Set location of input training data
parser.add_argument("--train", type=str, default=os.environ["SM_CHANNEL_TRAIN"])

# Set location of input validation data
parser.add_argument("--validation", type=str, default=os.environ["SM_CHANNEL_VALIDATION"])

args, _ = parser.parse_known_args()

data_train = pd.read_csv(f"{args.train}/train.csv")
data_validation = pd.read_csv(f"{args.validation}/validation.csv")
```

---

If you want to choose a different name for your input channel, the environment variable will change accordingly.

For example:

```py
# in your TrainingStep
inputs = {
            "myexample": TrainingInput(
                s3_data=step_process.properties.ProcessingOutputConfig.Outputs[
                    "myexample"
                ].S3Output.S3Uri
            )
        }

# in your training script
parser.add_argument("--myexample", type=str, default=os.environ["SM_CHANNEL_MYEXAMPLE"])
```